# Returning a specific value from inconsistently delimited csv file

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, csv, split

The issue seems simple but I'm stack in it since hours, here is what looks like my data:

```
\N
PARIS PREMIERE,1375,7
RTL9,1376,7
TV BREIZH,1162,7
C+ CINEMA,1594,7
\N
C+ SPORT,1595,7
OCS MAX,799,7
```

The output I want to have is:

```
1375
1376
1162
1594
1595
799
```

For this I run this code:

```
    list_data = data.split('\n')
    for line in list_data:
        for s in line.split(','):
            params = s.split('\n')
```

But it seems not working. If you have any Idea how I can solve my issue please Help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params = []
list_data = data.split('\n')
    for line in list_data:
        if len(line.split(',')) == 3
            params.append(line.split(',')[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter all undesirable delimeters:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv') as f:
  data = [int(i[-2]) for i in csv.reader(f) if len(i) > 1 or i[0] != '\\N']
  print(data)
```

Output:

```
[1375, 1376, 1162, 1594, 1595, 799]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way it use `pandas` to return the required list:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO(r"""\N
PARIS PREMIERE,1375,7
RTL9,1376,7
TV BREIZH,1162,7
C+ CINEMA,1594,7
\N
C+ SPORT,1595,7
OCS MAX,799,7""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, delimiter='~')

res = df.loc[df[0] != r'\N', 0].str.split(',').str[-2].astype(int).tolist()
```

Result:

```
[1375, 1376, 1162, 1594, 1595, 799]
```

You can then do what you like with this list, e.g. write to a file, use elsewhere in your program, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much I did not think about using **pandas** your code works like magic!